# ADD picture to SUPER and Close old window to open new

Tags: java, swing

i search on the google answer to my questions and found it, but i dont know how use it.
q1. how to add picture to my program and text.
q2. how i can close old windows when i open new ( i read about dispole and setVisiable but i cant do it ).
my program:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        new Main().setVisible(true);

    }

    private static String[] args; // OTWORZ inny program
    private Main(){

        super("PROJEKT"); // tytuł okna
        setSize(600,600); // rozmiar okna
        setResizable(false); // blokuj powiększenie manualne okna
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // na krzyzuku zamknie

        Toolkit zestaw = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); // get defaulttoolkit , zestaw który pobierze
        Dimension rozmiarEkranu = zestaw.getScreenSize(); // rozdzielczosc ekranu a nastepnie 
        int wysEkranu = rozmiarEkranu.height;           // wstawi otworzy okno na środku
        int szerEkranu = rozmiarEkranu.width;

        // umiesc ramke na srodku ekranu i dodaj tytuł

        setSize(szerEkranu / 2, wysEkranu / 2);
        setLocation(szerEkranu / 4, wysEkranu / 4);

        setLayout (new BorderLayout());
        /*
         * FlowLayout
         * GridBagLayout
         * GridLayout
         * BorderLayout
         */

        JButton klawisz = new JButton ("START");
        klawisz.addActionListener (new Action1());
        add(klawisz, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar(); // Górne MENU
        JMenu file = new JMenu("Plik"); // wstaw PLIK do menu
        JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("Zamknij"); // do pliku wstaw zamknij
        close.addActionListener(this);
        file.addSeparator(); // wstaw przerwe
        file.add(close);

        bar.add(file);
        setJMenuBar (bar);


    }
    static class Action1 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Menu.main(args); // otwiera inny program
        new Main().setVisible(false); // HERE I DONT KNOW HOW TO CLOSE OLD WINDOW
    }


    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String name = e.getActionCommand();

        if(name.equals("Zamknij")) { // zamknij program jak wcisne przycisk zamknij
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *"i read about dispole and setVisiable but i cant do it"*  I'm not surprised, since you cannot even manage to spell them correctly. :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson: English is does not appear to be the OP's first language, which likely helps explain his spelling issues.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  In many cases I'd ignore spelling errors  (note how I did not comment on "cant".), but *not when they can be copy/pasted from (or at least checked against) the JavaDocs.*  OTOH one thing that prompted my comment was the sheer laziness of typing in all lower case.  Even if there are languages which do not have the concept of case, it is not *too* hard to remember to capitalize the first letter of every sentence, as well as the word 'I'.

Answer (score 2):

1) don't create a new `JFrame` for new image, don't do that, those `containers` are present in memory untill current JVM instance exist

2) look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), then you never need something similair

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your calling `setVisible(false)` on a new instance your Main class, and this instance is not the one that is currently being displayed. To answer your direct question, you need to call `setVisible(false)` on the current instance of Main which you would get with Main.this:

```
Main.this.setVisible(false);
```

But having said this, I'm with mKorbel (1+ to him), that you shouldn't even do this as it makes for an ugly user experience, but instead should swap *view* by using a CardLayout.

Comment: i put your code to my main and unfortunately doesnt work. plz repair my program to close window when i open new.